# How to ask your Boss politely to sign a document a little bit faster?

Tags: politeness

The paper is important. My current best version were:

*"Sehr geehrter Herrn ...,*

*Dürfte ich die ... Dokument möglichst schnellsten bekommen?"*

But it seems a little bit rude for me. Practically, I really won't give *him* orders. I only ask my paper from him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These, I spontaneously call them  *Ausfluchtsformulierungen* (*evasion phrases*) now – I'm pretty sure there exists a better, official term[[1](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#H.C3.B6flichkeitsform)]. (If not, I hereby grant permission for citation (–:

- *dürfte ich*, *darf ich* → "Sorry, but no, not now."
- *möchte ich* → "Sorry, but I don't have the time to take care of what you want atm."
- *würden sie* → "I would if I had time atm."
- *"so schnell es Ihnen möglich ist"* → "Sorry, in three weeks is the fastest possible."

... give the addressee the opportunity to...evade.

> Sehr geehrter / Lieber [depending on how close you are to the boss] Herr N.!
>
> Um [den Auftrag / die Bestellung / die Lieferung] **AAA** ... [be specific]
> ... für PPP ... [involve persons]
> ... bis **TTT** ... [give a *concrete* point in time, depending on how urgent it is, use an uneven time, e.g 11:53, this attracts attention: "Why the heck exactly at 11:53?"]
> ... erledigen zu können, bitte ich Sie, das Angebot / den Vertrag ... [be specific, *Dokument* is too general]
> ... **RRR** [include a comprehensible reference your boss is supposed to know] ...
> ... zu unterzeichnen und mir rasch zukommen zu lassen.
>
> Mit freundlichem Gruß [you only greet once with one writing (assumed that you don't suffer from schizophrenia ;-) and it attracts attention since it's not that usual compared to the plural]
>
> N.N.

Use formatting, if possible, to highlight crucial parts.

Which then, for instance, becomes:

> Lieber Herr Müller!
>
> Um Ihre Frage *„How to ask your Boss politely to sign a document a little bit faster?“* für unsere geneigten Leser **bis morgen, 17:21** zufriedenstellend beantworten zu können, bitte ich Sie, meine Antwort vom 19. Oktober als akzeptierte zu zeichnen und mir so die Reputationspunkte rasch zukommen zu lassen.
>
> Mit freundlichem Gruß
>
> Hans Mustermann

---

PS:

1. [↑](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/how-to-ask-your-boss-politely-to-sign-a-document-a-little-bit-faster#official_term) See [Konjunktiv II, Höflichkeitsform](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#H.C3.B6flichkeitsform): *"Die Möglichkeitsform dient hier dazu, um den Wunsch oder den Anspruch auf Erfüllung förmlich abzumildern."* AFAIU you don't want "abmildern". You need it more or less urgently, don't you?

Comment: Antwort riecht nach "Meta" (was keine Kritik ist) !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: „Meta“ wovon? (Kritik ist absolut erwünscht, sofern sie konstruktiv ist.)

Comment: "Meta" im Sinne, daß der semantische Inhalt des Briefs sich auf die Frage selbst bezieht. Dies ist keine Kritik, weder konstruktiv noch nicht konstruktiv, aber eine Bemerkung fûr Leute, die [Selbstreferenzialität](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selbstreferenzialit%C3%A4t) amüsiert.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Ach, das meinst Du. Freut mich, dass ich Dir einen vergnüglichen Moment bescheren konnte. Den hatte ich beim Schreiben auch.

Answer (score 7):

Your boss likely is a very busy man so I'd recommend to keep the wording as short as possible and to the point, e.g.

> Sehr geehrter Herr *[Name]*,
>
> darf ich Sie *(noch einmal)*<sup>*</sup> an die Unterschrift unter mein *Dokument*<sup>**</sup> erinnern?
>
> Vielen Dank!
>   Ihr
>   *[signature]*
>
> <sup>* *only if you had asked before*</sup>
>   <sup>** *specify the nature of the document*</sup>

Pro tip: in case it is really urgent you may get a much better and immediate outcome if you bribed his secretary (which could be as little effort as nice phone call to her).

Comment: please don't propagate bribery ;)

Comment: Warum "unter mein Dokument" und nicht "unter meinem Dokument" ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: guter Hinweis - ich denke beides ist zulässig, bin mir aber unsicher.

Comment: Ach, es freut mich, daß sogar für Leute die deutsch so gut beherrschen wie du, der richtige  Fall nicht ganz eindeutig ist.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: _„unter mein“_ ist relativ/dynamisch/aktiv, i.S.v. „wohin?“, „ich gehe unter mein dach“. _„unter meinem“_ ist absolut/statisch/passiv, i.S.v. „wo?“, „ich stehe unter meinem dach“. Da das Unterschreiben ja ein aktiver Vorgang ist, ist „unter mein“ richtig. (Obwohl vielen das gar nicht auffallen würde und sie eins wie´s andere sähen.) „an die Unterschrift unter meinem Dokument [könnte ich jemanden] erinnern“, der sie schon darunter gesetzt hat, aber es z.B. vergessen hat oder nichts mehr davon wissen will.

Answer (score 3):

> Sehr geehrter Herr ABC,
>
> hiermit möchte ich Sie noch einmal an mein Anliegen XY erinnern,
>   welches für mich von großer Wichtigkeit ist.  Es würde mir sehr
>   entgegenkommen, wenn Sie es baldigst erledigten.
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen XYZ

Comment: ["möchte", "würde", ...](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/17298/10812)

Comment: I would use "bald". "baldigst" can sound condescending.

Comment: Das muss man abwägen. Baldigst betont nocheinmal die zeitliche Wichtigkeit, kann aber als Respektlos verstanden werden. Dafür macht es eindeutig klar, dass der Sachverhalt so schnell wie möglich abgegolten werden soll. Bald hingegen ist zu unklar. Morgen? In 2 Wochen? Nächsten Monat?

Comment: Wenn nicht unangemessen,würde ich noch kurz schreiben, wieso es für Dich dringend ist, und bis wann Du es brauchst. "Da die Frist für XY morgen abläuft bitte ich Sie mir heute noch das Dokument Z zu unterschreiben."

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a bit more subtle, I think. Try something like

> Sehr geehrter Herr ...,
>
> Haben Sie schon eine Gelegenheit gehabt, einen Blick auf mein Paper zu werfen?

Comment: If it is a document that has to be signed, "Paper" should be translated to "Dokument".

Comment: Not necessarily, but impossible to say without further information.

Comment: @Ingmar I really love subtlety, too. But, my experience, it isn't understood by everybody. And here the two possible answers are "No.", "Yes.". Neither with an (explicite) request for further activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask your Boss to get you a paper a bit faster, your Boss already know you need this paper. So you could ask like this:

> Sehr geehrter Herr Boss-Name,
>
> da ich das bereits erwähnte Dokument dringend benötige, möchte ich Sie daran erinnern mir das genannte Dokument so schnell es Ihnen möglich ist, zukommen zu lassen. Ich danke schon einmal im Vorfeld für Ihre Hilfe.

here you do not give your Boss any order you just remind him about the paper and add the information that you need the paper as fast as possible and thank him for his help.

Comment: "schonmal" ist ein wenig salop. "schon einmal im Vorfeld" wäre besser.

Comment: I do agree and will edit the answer!

Comment: @user3868224 "das bereits erwähnte Dokument" and "das genannte Dokument" is a repetition of content. "möglich" → see [my answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/17298/10812). I'd say "Im Voraus" (One _r_ only! ;-) rather than "Im Vorfeld" but that's personal taste.