# schonmal vs. schon mal

Tags: spelling

I checked on [www.duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schon_mal) and it says both versions are correct,
however they recommend `schon mal` without saying why.

On another site I found something that said `schonmal` is wrong and that
it should always be `schon mal`.

Can anyone give a sensible explanation?

Just in comparison: `nochmal (short for noch einmal)` and `erstmal (short for erst einmal)` are usually written together (have never seen them separate and I believe this is also considered incorrect). Why then would `schon mal / schonmal (short for schon einmal)` not follow the same rule?

Comment: I've seen "noch einmal" separate.

Comment: Most notably in the question right below yours on the main page of german.stackexchange: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/how-to-ask-your-boss-politely-to-sign-a-document-a-little-bit-faster

Comment: Of course "noch einmal" is separate, just like "erst einmal" and "schon einmal." Please re-read my question which talks about the short forms "nochmal," "erstmal," and "schonmal / schon mal."

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding here. It sounds like you're saying you've never seen "noch einmal". You say "(have never seen them separate and I believe this is also considered incorrect)".

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you mean. You have never seen "noch mal" and "erst mal".

Comment: @MillieSmith Yes, correct. I edited my question so it is more obvious what I mean. :)

Comment: I think I remember a rule of thumb saying single word if _+ig_ or _+s_ can be appended, two words otherwise: _*schonmals_ and _*schonmalig_ are strange at least, so split _schon mal_. Personally, I tend to affix _mal_ almost always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why Duden recommends to separate *schon mal, noch mal*, and *erst mal* is because they are (colloquially originated) short forms for

> schon einmal
>   noch einmal
>   erst einmal

Note the difference to those compounds where *-mal* is not a shortened form but  lost its separate meaning in the compound:

> einmal (zweimal, dreimal,...)
>   manchmal
>   erstmal**s**
>   mehrmal**s**
>   ...

<sub>**Additional references:**

[canoo.net - nochmal/noch mal](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Reform/trennung/adverbialphrasen.jsp?context=OSepRule_MW-Adv&start=56)

[Amtliche Rechtschreibregeln *(via canoo.net)*](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GetrZusammen/pgf39.html?MenuId=OfficialSpelling114)

[Wörterverzeichnis *(PDF)*](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GetrZusammen/pgf39.html?MenuId=OfficialSpelling114)</sub>

Comment: To get a bit meta: "schon einmal" has to have originated from "schon ein Mal". :)

Comment: @J0hj0h yeah that's where it came from. See the links I gave on when to still capitalize *Mal*.

Answer (score 2):

Since "einmal" and "nochmal" are frequently written as one word, I don't see a rock-hard argument to bring against "schonmal". However, an n being followed by an m is quite rare in German, especially in the middle of a word. It makes "schonmal" a little weird to read in my mind.

But as Takkat pointed out – it's a colloquialism. In a private E-mail or text message, the issue becomes a mere matter of taste. If, on the other hand, you were writing, say, a novel where one of the characters uses that expression, you'd use "schon mal" unless you want to make a point of slurry pronunciation.

Comment: I see dry-soil-hard arguments, at least. +1 for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I would write "schon mal". Wenn I see " schonmal" I have to read it twice to get what is meant.

Comment: Me too. Is it an orthographically incorrect „Mal“ (mark) to „schonen“ (go easy on)? Or an orthographically incorrect meal if you suffer from an upset stomach (Schonmahl)? Language is fun. The „Deppenleerzeichen“ is spreading like a virus and on the other hand they don't use spaces if they really make sense.

Comment: @GeriBroser Sagt der Fitnessarzt zum Trainer: "Schon mal schon mal deine Spieler für das Champions-League Spiel". ;)

Comment: :-) And, BTW, _infrage_, _zurzeit_ etc. are equally ugly. I'm really waiting for _inrechung_, _zurdiskussion_ etc. to come.

Comment: @ Geri Broser - Yes, you are right, one can exaggerate the writing together of words.

Answer (score 0):

Schonmal and schon mal still have the same meaning. I use both of them.