# Purpose of "schon mal" in "Nein, fahrt schon mal vor!"

Tags: meaning

My friend was asked whether he wanted to travel home with his colleagues on the train and he responded:

> Nein, fahrt schon mal vor!

I know that *vorfahren* is a separable verb to mean "to ride along" but when I looked at the definition of "schon mal" or "schon einmal" I found it meant "ever / before / already" which made no sense.

Is there a reasonable definition of "schon mal"?

Comment: The meaning in context is _ride ahead already_ (at least roughly).

Comment: Additional information. There is a difference between "**vorfahren**" (Harry fahr den Wagen vor = Harry drive the car "to the front" - this relates to the location - not the last parking lot but bring the car to where we are so we can leave immediately) and "**vor fahren**" in your example. Here it means "drive before me" with a chronological relation. It says you can start your trip now - I'll start mine late, after you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [schonmal vs. schon mal](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17308/schonmal-vs-schon-mal)

Comment: @äüö: the "duplicate" is about the spelling. not the meaning. Answers there will not help here. It merits an own question.

Comment: @puck Right. The distinction between **vorfahren** and **vor fahren** becomes clearer when one knows that in the latter **vor** is the shortened form of the adverb **voraus**.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main usage cases of *schon mal*

1. Referring to the past, as you mentioned in the question, as ever/before/already/sometimes (and short for *"schon einmal"*)

   > Warst du schon mal in China?
   >   Das kommt schon mal vor
2. Referring to the present and immediate future the use is more colloquial. It usually means something like "go ahead", "go on", "in the meantime" or "meanwhile"

   > Geh schon mal vor, ich komme nach
   >   Das Essen ist gleich fertig, decke schon mal den Tisch

You example could be translated as "No, go ahead" or "No, don't wait for me"

The spelling *"schon mal"* is preferred over *"schonmal"*. This is discussed here: [schonmal-vs.-schon-mal](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17308/schonmal-vs-schon-mal)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not that good in German but I guess "this time rather". That translates to in meaning  :  I could go with my colleague but this time I would rather take the train.

Comment: You've misunderstood the sentence

Comment: I see. I thought the subject of fahrt was 'Ich' not 'Du'. :)

Comment: but I think your answers "go ahead", "go on", "in the meantime" or "meanwhile" are almost sound like my answer "this time rather". just my feeling.

Comment: "This time I would rather take **the train**" is your mistake. Presumably all the  colleagues take the same train line, so the example becomes "No, go ahead" implying "This time I'd rather take **a later train**". The implicit subject of *fahrt* is *ihr* because it's an imperative plural