# Wie fragt man einen Chef Papiere zu unterzeichnen, aber ohne "du" oder "Sie" zu verwenden?

Tags: formality

Mein aktuelles Problem ist sehr ähnlich [zu meinem vorherigen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/how-to-ask-your-boss-politely-to-sign-a-document-a-little-bit-faster). Es geht darum, einen Chef zu bitten, schneller Papiere zu unterzeichnen.

Es sollte schon höflich sein, weil er ein Chef ist, aber nicht zu höflich, was auch problematisch wäre.

Und ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich "du" oder "Sie" benutzen sollte, also wäre es sehr nützlich, wenn ich beide Pronomen einfach vermeiden könnte.

Daneben gibt es noch das Ziel, dass es nicht so aussehen darf, als ob ich ihm einen Befehl geben würde. Es sollte eine Bitte von einer tieferen Stufe sein.

Meine aktuelle beste Idee wäre:

> *"Sehr geehrter Herr X,
>
>   Es tut mir leid die Störung. Hätten unsere Papiere unterschrieben werden können?
>
>   Mit freundlichem Grüßen"*

Aber praktisch klingt es mir doch sehr wie ein Befehl und scheint auch auch nicht ganz richtig zu sein. Ich kann es einfach nicht ohne Befehl *und* ohne Pronomen formulieren.

Comment: Ich habe ein paar Korrekturen vorgenommen. Erstmal weiß ich nicht, was "sehr höchlich und weih" bedeuten soll, aber der ganze Satz klang nicht sehr gut, deswegen habe ich mir die Freiheit genommen, ihn grundlegend zu ändern. Alles anderes sind kleine Korrekturen, so dass es etwas weniger hakelig klingt. Falls dir meine Änderungen nicht passen, feel free to rollback.

Comment: Wenn Du jemand mit "Sehr geehrter Herr X" ansprichst hast Du die Entscheidung bereits zugunsten des Siezens getroffen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ich wollte kurz nachfragen, ob die Papiere schon unterzeichnet sind?
>   Ich wollte kurz nachfragen, ob Sie/du die Papiere schon unterzeichnet haben/hast?

Ein paar Anmerkungen:

1. "Es tut mir leid die Störung" ist kein gutes Deutsch. Vorschlag: "Es tut mir leid Sie zu stören" oder "Verzeihen Sie die Störung". Wohlbemerkt hat beides eine Anrede. Das ist aber kein Problem, weil …
2. … eine persönliche Anrede würde ich nicht unbedingt vermeiden. Persönlicher bedeutet auch immer freundlicher. Daher würde ich von meinen beiden Sätzen oben, den zweiten bevorzugen. Soll es wirklich ohne Anrede sein, funktioniert Variante eins.
3. Jedoch unter der Annahme, dass der Chef vielbeschäftigt ist, sollte man sich kurz und knapp halten. Formulierungen mit der Kernaussage "Entschuldigen Sie die Störung", wie auch immer diese letztlich sind, sind unnötig. Komm direkt zum Punkt. Problem nur, ein schlichtes "Sind die Papiere schon unterschrieben?" ist sehr plump, daher empfehle ich eine kurze Einleitung, wie oben gezeigt.
4. "Hätten unsere Papiere unterschrieben werden können" ist zwar grammatikalisch, sagt aber nicht das aus, was du wissen möchtest. Bevor ich mit komplizierten Erklärungen anfange, denke ich, eine treffende Übersetzung ins Englische für diesen Satz wäre: "Had it been possible to sign the papers". Deine Frage ist aber: "Are the papers already signed".
5. Es gibt Menschen, die leider die implizite Frage hinter "sind die Papiere schon unterzeichnet" gerne ignorieren. Eine konkretere Aufforderung, die Papiere bald unterschrieben zuzustellen, könnte lauten "Ich bitte Sie darum, mir die Papiere baldmöglichst unterschrieben zurückzugeben." Alles in allem gibt es aber zig Möglichkeiten, und das ist wirklich nur eine von vielen.
6. Ich hoffe, dass dem Chef auch bewusst ist, was "die Papiere" sind. Eventuell nochmals erwähnen, um welche es sich handelt.

Comment: Eine Alternative ohne "unterzeichnen".... "Ich wollte mich mal erkundigen wie der Stand mit XY (Vertrag, etc) ist."

Answer (score 1):

Einige weitere Beispiele:

1. `Sind die Papiere schon unterschrieben?` sowie `Sind die Papiere schon fertig?` – eine sehr direkte Ansprache ohne direkte Ansprache (der Person). Kann je nach Betonung als Befehl oder unfreundlich verstanden werden. Diese Frage würde wahrscheinlich eher der Chef denn seine Mitarbeiter stellen.
2. `Kann ich die fertigen Papiere wieder haben?` – Damit fragst du indirekt nach dem Arbeitsstand und weist den Chef sozusagen freundlich darauf hin, dass du mit ihnen weiter arbeiten musst. Allerdings kann das als Anschuldigung, man sei zu langsam, (miss)verstehen.
3. `Wann kann ich (in etwa) mit den unterschriebenen Papieren rechnen?` – Mein persönlicher Favorit. Damit zwingst du den Chef, sich selbst auf einen Termin festzulegen, und beweist damit vorausschauendes Arbeiten und Planung.
4. (Nicht ganz ernst gemeint) `Hat Er seine Unterschrift schon gesetzt?` – Eine Anrede ohne du/Sie für den unwahrscheinlichen Fall, dass dein Chef ein Witzbold ist und du von adligem Geblüt.